# Android Hello World App "activity_my" file different from described

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am new to Android development so I decided to start off by following the instructions on the tutorial on http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html.

After creating a blank activity and running it, the next step is to create a UI. It is implied by the instructions that the activity_my.xml file contains a RelativeLayout root view and a TextView child view. However, upon opening the file this is what I found

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_my" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Which is apparently not what should have been produced. I have searched through other questions but haven't found this particular problem anywhere else. Any help or insight would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You're either a) not using Android Studio (which the tutorial uses); b) selected a different project template c) using a different version of Android Studio than the tutorial. Believe it or not, even a deep pockets company like Google can have problems keeping tutorial information current.

Comment: Yes, as @MarsAtomic said, it is dependent on the template that you select and the Android version. Today I happen to see this layout for my activity_main xml. No worries, you can replace the entire parent tag and its contents with the layout that you found in tutorial

Comment: @Santhana thank you so much! I'll just go ahead and replace it with the template code then. Hopefully the tutorial gets updated soon.

Comment: @MarsAtomic thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The layout your xml file contains depends by what you chose when you create the project in your IDE (Blank Activity, Activity with Fragments, ecc...).

If you want to use the code of the tutorial you can just replace the code generated by your IDE and use the one provided by the tutorial:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

With this you'll have a simple activity with a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Thank you! The tutorial actually says to use a blank activity, which I did, so I think it might be that the default IDE generated code changed with the newest version of Android Studio. But it doesn't matter cos I can still replace it with the one from the tutorial anyway